# One-One ORM and insertion in DB

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a one-one mapping of classes Employee and Department. I have Bean classes in domain. I have a front end JSP which is a Employee form. This form has a drop down box which lists all the departments available.

Now I need to do an insert operation of the employee, using hibernate.

```
<form:form action="add" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    <div>
        <form:label path="emailAddress">Email</form:label>
        <form:input path="emailAddress" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <form:label path="deptartment">Department</form:label>
        <form:select path="department">
        <form:options items="${departmentList}" />
        </form:select>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getAddEmployeeSettingsPage(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
            BindingResult result) {

        System.out.println(employee);
        return "empsettings";
    }
```

Now, employee object has no reference to department. What should I do to fetch employee object in the controller along with associated department reference. Hope I am clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cool.. got it here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425154/java-springmvc-get-parameter-in-the-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the soln without need to inject:

```
<div>
    <form:label path="department.departmentId">Department</form:label>
    <form:select path="department.departmentId">
    <form:options items="${departmentList}" itemValue="departmentId" itemLabel="departmentName"/>
    </form:select>
</div>
```

Just associate the department in the combo box.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Inject a DAO to the controller, have the controller fetch from the department to associate with the employee from the DAO, and persist the employee.

Ideally, you'd probably want to wrap all this logic into a service method, so the service would just take an employee, and persist it with the appropriate Department.  Also, wouldn't the relation be many-to-one, many employee's belong to one department.  Otherwise, you'd have employee Bob who belongs to Department Bob, employee Sue belongs to Department Sue, etc.